# Will saplings drop if leaves are destroyed by piston?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to build a redstone machine that makes chopping down trees more efficient. Speficically, I want to arrange for leaves to be destroyed by a piston (strictly speaking: by a block pushed by a piston) so that I don't have to do it manually/wait. In this scenario, will saplings drop normally?

(With early prototypes, I get the impression that I get fewer sapling than expected, and there's always a considerable number of left-over leaves so I'm not sure where the few saplings that I get are coming from.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaves destroyed by a piston or pushed block can drop saplings and/or apples.

Keep in mind the drop rate of saplings is 5% (2.5% with jungle leaves),
so a low yield should be expected.

It might be worth pointing out, that a TNT explosion has a 100% drop rate (*no increased drop loss*) since version 1.14 (snapshot 19w11a) as seen [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/TNT#History), so destroying the leaves with carefully placed TNT could be more efficient than using multiple pistons.

The drop rates are taken from the [Minecraft Wiki page for leaves](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Leaves#Usage).

Answer (score 5):

Yes they do.

See tree farm videos. Lot of them available on YouTube..